# react-native-navigation Tab Bar Icon from Android Drawables and iOS xcassets

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation as a preferred navigation approach in our react-native application. We are planning on using the hybrid approach for icons where we still add icons in xcassets and drawables.

I am seeing a specific issue with icons for tab-bar on android when loading them from drawables. My code is below which works perfectly fine for iOS:

**Tabs Definition:**

```
const Tabs = [
{
    label: 'Home',
    screen: 'HomeScreen',
    //icon: require('../../assets/images/test.png'),
    icon: { uri: 'icon_home', scale: Dimensions.get('window').scale },
    selectedIcon: { uri: 'icon_home', scale: Dimensions.get('window').scale },
    title: 'Home'
},
{
    label: 'Message',
    screen: 'MessageScreen',
    icon: { uri: 'icon_home', scale: Dimensions.get('window').scale },
    selectedIcon: { uri: 'icon_home_selected', scale: Dimensions.get('window').scale },
    title: 'Message'
}]
```

**Navigation Code:**

```
_navigateToHomeScreen = () => {
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs: Tabs,
  tabsStyle: tabsStyle,
  appStyle: tabsStyle
 });
}
```

**Tab Styles:**

```
tabStyle = {
  tabBarBackgroundColor: Colors.DefaultWhiteColor,
  tabBarButtonColor: Colors.NavigationBarItemColor,
  tabBarLabelColor: Colors.NavigationBarItemColor,
  tabBarSelectedButtonColor: Colors.PrimaryButtonBackground,
  tabBarSelectedLabelColor: Colors.PrimaryButtonBackground,
  forceTitlesDisplay: true
}
```

**What we have tried:**

- I tried using the same image in a list view and it shows up correctly so I don't think that react-native is not able to find the image from drawable.
- I tried specifying the height/width (without scale) for the image and it still does not work.
- If I use require('') to load an image which is in JS then it works correctly but we want to use drawables.
- I tried removing **scale** and it still doesn't work.
- For iOS, loading image from xcassets and using it in tab bar works without any issues.

**Version Information:**

react-native: 0.52.0
react-native-navigation: 1.1.314
Android-Version: Emulator: Android 5.1, Android 6.0

We are running out of options. The final solution would be to use local images and not images from native.

Any help is appreciated.

**Note:This question is not for react-navigation. It is for react-native-navigation library by wix available at https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/.**